# joomla php variable have a random "." character behind numeric value

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I have this website which is powered by Joomla!. The website have a custom component which I built to allow event registrations and the invoice number are coded to have auto increment capability.

An example of a invoice number would be like DOMAINNAME-00015-0000000055. Do note that "00015" is the event ID and "0000000055" is the increment. So after this invoice the next number would be DOMAINNAME-00015-0000000056 and so on.

So there is this event recently which is hosted and there are about 1500 registrations. However, I noticed that there are a few bookings which have their invoice number generated wrong. An example would be like DOMAINNAME-0015.-0000000057, so if you notice the event ID is "0015." instead of "00015". I checked the access log and noticed that when the event ID variable is passed from the view it is actually passing "15." instead of just "15".

The user will need to go to the event details page and click on this link to make a reservation of their booking. So I am suspecting that on the event details page the variable that contains the event ID that is added to the link is rendered as "15." instead of "15" in cases where the invoice number is generated wrongly.

But the question now is why? I have not seen cases where value are not consistent, there are about 6 cases out of the 1500 which have this issue. The event ID should be pulling from the database and it is a flat value of 15.

Any experienced guys know why is this happening?

[Edit]

Below is the code for the link where users will click to make their first initial reservation. The variable "cid" here is supposed to be "15" but from the access log of the web hosting server the users entered with a link which have the value of the variable "cid" set to "15." instead of "15" which results in the error of the invoice generation. The array "$post" is grabbed using the joomla! core function "JRequest::get();" which I think should not be the issue.

```
$apply_individual = 'index.php?option='.$post['option'].'&task=default&view=eventregistration&cid='.$post['cid'].'&type=individual';
```

This is the part where invoice number are generated.

```
function generateInvoiceID($event_id) {
    // Get a database object
    $db =& JFactory::getDBO();  
    $query = "SELECT * FROM #__db_name ORDER BY id";
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $results = $db->loadObjectList();

    $order_id = array();

    if(isset($results)) {
        foreach($results as $result) {
            if(!empty($result->invoice_id)) {
                $invoice_event_id = substr($result->invoice_id, 6, -11);
                $check_event_id = str_pad($event_id, 5, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
                $get_invoice_number = substr($result->invoice_id, -10);

                if($invoice_event_id == $check_event_id) {
                    //$order_id[] = $result->invoice_id;
                    $order_id[] = $get_invoice_number;
                }
            }
        }

        // get max id
        if(isset($order_id) && !empty($order_id)) {
            $max_id = max($order_id);
            //$max_id = substr($max_id, 12);
            $max_id++;
        } else {
            $max_id = 1;
        }

        $invoice_number = str_pad($max_id, 10, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
        $event_id = str_pad($event_id, 5, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
        $invoice_id = 'DOMAINNAME-'.$event_id.'-'.$invoice_number;
        $invoice_id = strtoupper($invoice_id);
    }

    return $invoice_id;
}
```

As you can see the event_id is converted to 5 digits using php function "str_pad". The increment number is working perfectly though. I also noticed that if I add a "." in the link which users will click I will generate a invoice number like "DOMAINNAME-0015.-0000000058". But I have no idea why a value for example "15." will be passed into the link in the first place. This issue does not affect all the invoice numbers but only a few like 5 out of 1500.

Comment: I think you need to include some code snippets too, for example, if the flat value is 15 then how you pad it to get 00015?

Comment: i was assuming there was no source code to show ! Like it was locked up in a binary or something

Comment: Sorry for the missing code samples. I updated the question with the code samples. I am lost at why this is happening.

Comment: Are you saying that it happens sometimes but not all the time? Do you know what to do to make it happen? If it is bad user input I would sanitize the input first ... you should never take input directly from users without sanitizing it.  In JForm you can use validate="Int"  or if you aren't using JForm use JInputFilter int.

Comment: @Elin It does not happen all the time. It seems to be like a random bad input from the URL which I am not sure if it is caused by the user or by a badly generated HTML (find it difficult to confirm).

I added an additional check before the reservation for the event to confirm that the input for the event ID only contains numbers and not anything else (0-9 only). And in the case where it contains stuffs other than 0-9 the user will be redirected to a page where it says "There is an error in your request." and no reservation will be made for that request.

Comment: It's really hard to diagnose if you can't reproduce consistently. But you should make sure to sanitize all your inputs.

Comment: @Elin Yup. I added the check before user can make a reservation now.